# Popover on hover should disappear when page is scrolled - Material UI (MUI) v5 for React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

When I follow the MUI v5 standard pattern to display a popover when another element is hovered over, it works fine, except when you

1. Hover over the element
2. Without moving the mouse, use the scroll wheel to scroll the document
3. The popover remains visible even after the triggering element has scrolled away

This is the usual code snippet:

```
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", overflow: "auto" }}>
      <div style={{ height: 1000 }}>
        <Typography
          aria-owns={open ? "mouse-over-popover" : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
          onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}
        >
          Hover and then scroll
        </Typography>
        <Popover
          id="mouse-over-popover"
          className={classes.popover}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.paper
          }}
          open={open}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: "bottom",
            horizontal: "left"
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "left"
          }}
          onClose={handlePopoverClose}
          disableRestoreFocus
        >
          <Typography>I use Popover.</Typography>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here's a [full working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-scrolling-demo-scutp?file=/demo.js) demonstrating the problem.

How can I make the popover disappear when the user scrolls the document? I do not want to disable scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add an event listener that listens to scroll event to certain element (or to any element in the page) and invoke the `handlePopoverClose` event when the scroll event is triggered? Basically just add these lines to the component:

```
  ...
  // on mount, listen to scroll event on any element in the page (document, and its child)
  // if scroll is triggered, close the popover
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handlePopoverClose, true);
  }, []);

  // on unmount, remove the scroll event listener
  React.useEffect(
    () => () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handlePopoverClose, true);
    },
    []
  );
  ...
```

Here's the [working fork demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-scrolling-demo-forked-m6i1tn?file=/demo.js). Note that the `true` was set so that it adds the scroll event listener to any child element of the page. You could also only add the scroll event listener to specific element, but it wouldn't solve the problem when the scroll is caused by other element (or window).

Comment: Perfect. It was that true parameter that was the key.

Comment: Just fyi, you can shorten that up and use a single useEffect call:

    React.useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener("scroll", handlePopoverClose, true);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", handlePopoverClose, true);
      }
    }, []);

Comment: Interesting, I actually didn't know that, seems like I should learn functional react more. As for the answer though, i'd keep it as is so that I could keep those comments about lifecycle more easily